# How to remove an apostrophe from a string in a loop?

Tags: javascript, string, loops, replace

I currently have a loop generating a URL to appear on a page. I have a few URL's that have an apostrophe in the string that it returns. I am attempting to remove the apostrophe from the URL. I am familiar with the `.replace` method which is what I'm attempting to implement. I am declaring a variable at the start of the case and then using the variable `newUrl`

Code:

```
     } else {

 let newUrl = sectorHTML += "<a href=\"" + linkURLPart1 +  linkURLPart2 + jsonData.Column1[r].ReportURL + "/\">
  <span style=\"color:#000000;\">" 
//linkURLPart 1 = new ; linkUrlPart2 = article; 
json.DataColumn1[r].ReportUrl = people's-home
    sectorHTML += "<div>";
                   newUrl = newUrl.replace("'", "")

                    }
```

**Current output:** 
`/new/article/people's-home/`

**expected output:** 
`/new/article/peoples-home/`

Comment: Why are you assigning `json.DataColumn1[r].ReportUrl = people's-home` *after* you put it into `newUrl`? And you need quotes around the value in the assignment.

Comment: You shouldn't do the replacement on `newUrl`, since there might be other apostrophes in the HTML. You should do it on `json.DataColumn1[r].ReportUrl` before concatenating it into the HTML.

Comment: And you should use a regular expression so you can replace multiple apostrophes.